# Edit summary says "example unpinned" even when it is not

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

If I find a topic that has a pinned example, and edit some other (not pinned) example from that topic, the resulting proposed change edit summary says that I unpinned an example:

[image: summary]

But the diff shows no change in pinning status (no [red background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcp4o.png)):

[image: diff]

If I then go to the proposed change and click edit button on the *pinned* example (retracting my change from the review), and, without changing anything, click "Amend", the updated edit summary no longer contains "example unpinned".
<sub>(Interestingly, this also causes another change: pinned example moves to the top of the diff, and the edited example is now second.)</sub>

Seems like some sort of inconsistency between the edit summary and the actual diff.

Comment: I've been noticing this too, but just thought I was going crazy instead of actually looking into it.

Comment: I had assumed that it was showing me that the pin was there in one version but gone the next in the side-by-side view; if this is not the case (as it looks to be after further inspection), I think the UI needs an update in addition to just fixing any under-the-hood bugs.

Comment: I rejected an edit once because it showed that it unpinned the example that I had just pinned. Which didn't make a lot of sense, considering the person submitting said edit had just approved my edit. Turns out, it actually didn't and the summary was just lying. Not sure how this kind of bug happens, but it definitely merits fixing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This (and some related bugs) has been fixed in the latest deploy.

The root issue was some buggy code that assumed that the pinned example was always being edited.

Comment: Good! But one more thing: if I create a draft or a proposed change that actually unpins an example, and then go and (retract and) edit that, the edit page shows the example as pinned again (forgets the unpin). Is it a related issue?