# Skipping review based on tag badge not working

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, documentation

According to the 4th August update:

> Users with a silver or gold tag badge (from Q&A) will skip review when they make an edit to that tag's documentation

I have a silver [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) badge in Q&A, and I just made an [edit that now apparently needs to be reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/82181) - what gives?

Have I misunderstood this or is it simply not working?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Changes to versions, and any changes that alter which example is *pinned* will always require review. See: [Proposed Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-proposed-changes) in the Help Center.

Comment: Would you give some insight into this distinction?  I was able to create the entire topic on my own due to a gold badge, but couldn't pin the main example when I noticed I forgot.  Not a huge deal, but there's not an actual explanation for the difference in the help page.

Comment: [Probably this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331794/edit-summary-says-example-unpinned-even-when-it-is-not), @davidism

Comment: Submitted my issue as a new bug, since it doesn't seem to be fixed by that change: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332519/text-only-documentation-edit-with-gold-badge-doesnt-skip-review

Comment: @davidism I'm seeing the same thing.  Basically, if a topic has a pinned example, any change to any example in that topic will go up for review (even for silver/gold tag badge holders)