# Text-only Documentation edit with gold badge doesn't skip review

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

I have a gold badge in [flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask) and was able to [create a topic without review](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/84346), as expected.  I then tried to edit it to remove a line I left in by mistake.  However, this change did not go through automatically, it went to review.

- I have the gold badge for the only tag involved in the edit.
- I did not edit the pinned example or versions, so it's not [Skipping review based on tag badge not working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332115/skipping-review-based-on-tag-badge-not-working).
- The edit summary does not say "example unpinned", so it's not [Edit summary says "example unpinned" even when it is not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331794/edit-summary-says-example-unpinned-even-when-it-is-not)

Since [the initial edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/84898) went in before some of the recent fixes mentioned above were deployed, and the edit was still waiting for review, I tried:

- Retracting and [resubmitting the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/84951).
- Retracting and discarding the edit, then creating a [completely new edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/84957).
  <sub>(This one was approved by other users.)</sub>

Neither worked.

I expect that my edit will go through without review, but it did not.

Comment: I've seen this happening as well, but it's not consistent. Larger edits don't appear to cause issues, unless you move an example. Moving examples appears to always force a review.

Comment: I'm seeing what looks like the same issue in the Android tag.  Basically, any edit to a topic that already has an example pinned goes to review, even if it doesn't pin or unpin any examples....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was some code that assumed a draft always *edited* the pinned example when trying to determine if the pin on a topic had been moved.

This has been fixed in the latest deploy.

Comment: Tested it by making an edit (to the pinned example no less) which went through without review: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/91073.  Thanks!